# Applying a transparent gradient from left to right in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, bitmap, gradient, transparent

I'm trying to create an algorithm in C/C++, which applies a uniform transparent gradient from left to right to a pixel buffer. As seen on the next image:

[image]

Next is so far my implementation. But the resulting image is not even close to what I need to achieve. Anyone can spot what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
void alphaGradient(uint32_t* pixelsBuffer, const int width, const int height)
{
    const short OPAQUE = 255;
    int pixelOffsetY, pixelIndex;
    short A, R, G, B;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        A = OPAQUE;

        pixelOffsetY = y * height;

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            pixelIndex = pixelOffsetY + x;

            A = (int)(OPAQUE - ((OPAQUE * x) / width));
            R = (pixelsBuffer[pixelIndex] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
            G = (pixelsBuffer[pixelIndex] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
            B = (pixelsBuffer[pixelIndex] & 0x000000FF);

            pixelsBuffer[pixelIndex] = (A << 24) + (R << 16) + (G << 8) + B;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the result differ from what you expect? The code looks fine at first glance.

Comment: You are mixing types heavily. On `A` you have a cast to a signed values and `(A << 24)` here you are shifting `short` by 24 bytes. Isn't that undefined behaviour? Maybe it's ok, but conversions are quite tricky at some points.

Comment: You made a simple error: `pixelOffsetY = y * height;` should be `pixelOffsetY = y * width;`

Comment: @luk32: 24 *positions*

Comment: @luk32 I think the usual integer promotions will come into play here, so starting with a `short` shouldn't hurt. But making everything `uint32_t` would be a quick test to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this code out but something like this should work :

```
void alphaGradient(uint32_t* pixelBuffer, const int width, const int height)
{
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        const DWORD src = pixelBuffer[i + j * width];
        const DWORD dst = MYBACKGROUNDCOLOR;

        const unsigned char src_A = (width - i) * 255 / width;
        const unsigned char src_R = (src & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
        const unsigned char src_G = (src & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
        const unsigned char src_B = (src & 0x000000FF);

        //const unsigned char dst_Alpha = (src & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
        const unsigned char dst_R = (dst & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
        const unsigned char dst_G = (dst & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
        const unsigned char dst_B = (dst & 0x000000FF);

        const unsigned char rlt_R = (src_R * src_A + dst_R * (255 - src_A)) / 255;
        const unsigned char rlt_G = (src_G * src_A + dst_G * (255 - src_A)) / 255;
        const unsigned char rlt_B = (src_B * src_A + dst_B * (255 - src_A)) / 255;
        //pixelBuffer[i + j*width] = (DWORD)(((255) << 24) | (((rlt_R)& 0xff) << 16) | (((rlt_G)& 0xff) << 8) | ((rlt_B)& 0xff));
        // or if you want to save the transparancy then 
        //pixelBuffer[i + j*width] = (DWORD)(((src_A) << 24) | (((src_R)& 0xff) << 16) | (((src_G)& 0xff) << 8) | ((src_B)& 0xff));
    }

}
}
```

But personally, I would try to use DirectX or OpenGL for this and write a good PixelShader. It would make this ALOT faster.

Comment: Just perfect. Works really as expected.

Comment: You are pre-multiplying the colors in this case. This may not be what the user is looking for... it very much depends on what is done with the image later, but I think the question did not say anything about changing the colors.

Comment: You are right about my src_A, It should be (width - i) * 255 / width; As you say "it very much depends on what is done with the image later". If you check my two comments at the end of my code I wrote two diffrent code lines, the first one is to save mixed colors and the secound one is to save transparancy, I then expect the user to delete the dst_X and rlt_X.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, since you only want to modify the alpha channel, you do not need to do anything with the colors. So the following would work too:

```
char *b((char *) pixelBuffer);
for(int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < width; ++i, b += 4)
    {
        *b = (width - i) * 255 / width;
    }
}
```

That's it. You could also eliminate the computation for each line by duplicating the data of the first line in the following lines:

```
// WARNING: code expects height > 0!
char *b((char *) pixelBuffer);
for(int i = 0; i < width; ++i, b += 4)
{
    *b = (width - i) * 255 / width;
}
int offset = width * -4;
for(int j = 1; j < height; ++j)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < width; ++i, b += 4)
    {
        *b = b[offset];
    }
}
```

I will leave as an exercise to you to change this double `for()` loop in a single `for()` loop, which would make it a little faster yet (because you'd have a single counter (variable b) instead of three).

---

Note that I do not understand how Mikael's answer would work as he uses the `* 255` in the wrong place in his computation of the alpha channel. With integer arithmetic, that's very important. So this should return 0 or 255:

```
(width - i) / width * 255
```

because if `value < width` then `value / width == 0`. And `(width - i)` is either `width` or a value smaller than `width`...